# ActionScript 3.0 Error #1010 - preloader function

Tags: actionscript-3

I am a Flash and ActionScript newbie. I am trying to follow a [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oC31Pc5SCHM) to make a preloader and I'm having a problem that the video didn't seem to address. I believe I have entered in all of the code correctly from the video. This is it:

```
stop();

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loaderF);

function loaderF(e:Event):void{
    var toLoad:Number = loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
    var loaded:Number = loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
    var total:Number = loaded/toLoad;
    if( loaded == toLoad ){
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loaderF);
        gotoAndStop(2);
    } else {
        preloader_mc.preloaderFill_mc.scaleX = total;
        preloader_mc.percent_txt.text = Math.floor( total * 100 ) + "%";
        preloader_mc.ofBytes_txt.text = loaded + "bytes";
        preloader_mc.totalBytes_txt.text = toLoad + "bytes";
    }
}
```

What I typed in doesn't generate a compiler error, but the output tells me:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
at preloader_fla::MainTimeline/loaderF()
```

And since I really don't have any experience outside of what I'm learning from this tutorial series, I don't know what to do to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Flash CS5, but you should be able to get the line # for where the error is occurring, I believe, by executing the SWF by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Once you get the line number, you should see that something on that line is null or not defined.  The error says it occurs in the function `loaderF()`, and looking at that code the only place such an error could occur is in the else block:

```
} else {
        preloader_mc.preloaderFill_mc.scaleX = total;
        preloader_mc.percent_txt.text = Math.floor( total * 100 ) + "%";
        preloader_mc.ofBytes_txt.text = loaded + "bytes";
        preloader_mc.totalBytes_txt.text = toLoad + "bytes";
    }
```

In the above code block, one of these things is not defined:
`preloader_mc.preloaderFill_mc`,
`preloader_mc.percent_txt`,
`preloader_mc.ofBytes_txt`,
`preloader_mc.totalBytes_txt`

Maybe your preloader movie clip is missing one of these objects...

Comment: Excellent, thank you, once I knew what to narrow it down to, I discovered I simply hadn't named given the fill symbol the proper instance name.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to turn on debugging found under `(File > Publish Settings > Flash (.swf) > Permit Debugging)`.  This will provide line numbers and allow additional debugging to help track down errors.

Secondly, in the code sample you've provided, you haven't declared a loader, so when you call on `loaderInfo`, it makes sense that flash complains about "a term is undefined". Although, technically, the loaderInfo object is a child of the event object.  Thus, `loaderInfo.bytesTotal` would become `e.loaderInfo.bytesTotal`, assuming you added the event listener to the loader object; currently yours is added to the timeline.

Bookmark Adobe's [Actionscript 3.0 Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html).  Use it.  As you begin your journey in Flash, this will be your indispensable handbook to speaking AS3. Specifically, you'll want to refer to the [Loader class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html).

Here's what you're likely missing in your code:

```
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("path/to/my/file"));
```

Your function `loaderF` is being called during every frame update to the screen (likely every .034 seconds).  You'd probably be happier with `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS` instead of `Event.ENTER_FRAME`.  If so, you'll also want to catch the complete event, and that'd look like this:

```
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
myLoader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loadProgress);

function loadComplete(e:Event):void {
    // Stuff to do when the file finishes loading.
}

function loadProgress(e:Event):void {
    var current:int = e.bytesLoaded;
    var total:int = e.bytesTotal;
    var percent:Number = current/total;

    // Update the readout of your loading progress.
}
```

Hopefully that points you in the right direction.  :)

Comment: Looks like my meeting delayed my answer.  Glad you found the solution!  Cheers.